# Vega RX 64, OpenCL, and Ubuntu 16.04 HWE

Tags: 16.04, drivers, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I currently have 4 Vega RX 64's connected, and Ubuntu is either only seeing one of them or is seeing all 4 as the same device.

**Running clinfo I get:**

```
Number of platforms:                             1
  Platform Profile:                              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:                              OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2482.3)
  Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:                               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:                           cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices


  Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:                               1
  Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                                     1002h
  Board name:                                    Device 687f
  Device Topology:                               PCI[ B#3, D#0, F#0 ]
  Max compute units:                             64
  Max work items dimensions:                     3
    Max work items[0]:                           256
    Max work items[1]:                           256
    Max work items[2]:                           256
  Max work group size:                           256
  Preferred vector width char:                   4
  Preferred vector width short:                  2
  Preferred vector width int:                    1
  Preferred vector width long:                   1
  Preferred vector width float:                  1
  Preferred vector width double:                 1
  Native vector width char:                      4
  Native vector width short:                     2
  Native vector width int:                       1
  Native vector width long:                      1
  Native vector width float:                     1
  Native vector width double:                    1
  Max clock frequency:                           1630Mhz
  Address bits:                                  64
  Max memory allocation:                         7287183769
  Image support:                                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:           128
  Max number of images write arguments:          8
  Max image 2D width:                            16384
  Max image 2D height:                           16384
  Max image 3D width:                            2048
  Max image 3D height:                           2048
  Max image 3D depth:                            2048
  Max samplers within kernel:                    26751
  Max size of kernel argument:                   1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:              1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                                     No
    Quiet NaNs:                                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:                       Yes
    Round to zero:                               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:                   Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:             Yes
  Cache type:                                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:                               64
  Cache size:                                    16384
  Global memory size:                            8573157376
  Constant buffer size:                          7287183769
  Max number of constant args:                   8
  Local memory type:                             Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                             65536
  Max pipe arguments:                            0
  Max pipe active reservations:                  0
  Max pipe packet size:                          0
  Max global variable size:                      7287183769
  Max global variable preferred total size:      8573157376
  Max read/write image args:                     64
  Max on device events:                          0
  Queue on device max size:                      0
  Max on device queues:                          0
  Queue on device preferred size:                0
  SVM capabilities:
    Coarse grain buffer:                         Yes
    Fine grain buffer:                           Yes
    Fine grain system:                           No
    Atomics:                                     No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:           0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:             0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:              0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     64
  Error correction support:                      0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:            0
  Profiling timer resolution:                    1
  Device endianess:                              Little
  Available:                                     Yes
  Compiler available:                            Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:                      Yes
    Execute native function:                     No
  Queue on Host properties:
    Out-of-Order:                                No
    Profiling :                                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:
    Out-of-Order:                                No
    Profiling :                                  No
  Platform ID:                                   0x7f4ada80c3f8
  Name:                                          gfx900
  Vendor:                                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:                       OpenCL C 1.2
  Driver version:                                1.1 (HSA,HSAIL)
  Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2
  Extensions:                                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp16 cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_khr_subgroups cl_khr_depth_images cl_amd_liquid_flash cl_amd_copy_buffer_p2p
```

**Running "lspci" I get:**

```
lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 687f (rev c1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 687f (rev c1)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 687f (rev c1)
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 687f (rev c1)
```

I am using an ASRock H81 PRO BTC R2.0 for the board, which from what I have read can handle more than 4 cards. I followed the steps to install amdgpu-pro on the AMD site and am only able to use one card while mining.

Any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Vega ROCm (the opencl component of the driver stack used for mining etc) requires pcie gen3 to work.  This is because it uses hardware system calls refered to as atomics that are not supported in gen1 or 2. Therefor all cards must be connected to gen3 capable pcie slots.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). Specifically it would be improved by including sources/citations when possible.

Comment: That would make sense. Thank your for that great answer!

Comment: @user783217, do  you have a reference for this ?